# По нажатию кнопки выдвигать справа экрана маленький layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Цель: создать некое "меню" СПРАВА, выдвигаться оно должно по нажатию кнопки в `NavigationTabBar`. (желательно заполнение адаптером)

Вопрос: как реализовать подобную идею (была идея создать при помощи `SwipeHorizontalMenuLayout` но не нашел как свайпить при помощи нажатия кнопки)

Comment: простейшее - на разметке делаешь скрытый слой FrameLayout с любой стороны экрана (это будет выдвижной элемент). При нажатии кнопки изменяешь ему видимость, анимируешь и делаешь что хочешь с ним. В сам FrameLayout можно поместить что угодно, в том числе и виджеты, работающие с адаптером.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте через `PopupMenu`. Применение очень простое:

1. Надо озаботиться якорным `View`, к которому будет привязан `PopupMenu`- то есть фактически место где он будет появляться на экране устройства. Для вашего случая вполне можно устроить невидимый `View`, который будет расположен СПРАВА. Якорный/Anchor `View` задается [в конструкторе](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html#PopupMenu(android.content.Context,%20android.view.View))
2. Дальше все как обычно - ресурс меню, инфлейт ну и т.д.

Можно использовать другой вариант (более продвинутый и покрасивше) - применить [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html), только надо задать ему флаг `android:layout_gravity=right` а внутри разместить `ListView` с подпиткой из адаптера. При нажатии на кнопку вызвать `openDrawer()` тогда он красиво с анимацией выдвинется.